# fadeSlideShow description onslide

Tags: jquery, fadein

I'm using fadeSlideShow onslide to control the display of images and their descriptions.

The current dev can be seen here : http://uat.hemingweb.com/homepage.php

The slide show is from here http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeinslideshow.htm

The issue I am having is sync'ing the text change with the images. Currently it looks as though the text changes once the image has loaded. I would like the test to fadein in sync with the images.

```
onslide:function(curimage, index){
  var imagearray=this.setting.imagearray    
  jQuery("#hometext").html(imagearray[index][3])
}
```

jQuery isn't my strong point, is there a way to initiate the text change sooner and fade it in?

At the minute each piece of text is attached to 2 images, I need to avoid the text fading in twice.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
setTimeout(function(){changeMyImage()}, 1000);
```

to use a timeout. the first parameter is the function which needs to be called, the second is the waiting time in milliseconds, so changeMyImage() is called after waiting 1 second.